# UITableView MoveRow Button position changing from right to left

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am developing one Arabic application in which I want a UITableview has right to left allurement for all the control , row delete button, row insertion button , row move button all should be align right left.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can create a custom cell and do whatever you want. Follow this [link text](http://www.e-string.com/content/custom-uitableviewcells-interface-builder)